# Set start date in Calendar RichFaces

Tags: java, jsf, calendar, richfaces

I need to set a start date in a calendar component richfaces. I have a variable called `dateInitial` in my ManagedBean that have a Date (i.e 2013-07-07 are lower limit date) and I configure my calendar component :

```
 <rich:calendar id="dateToEvaluate" popup="true" 
    required="true" requiredMessage="Required Field"
    buttonIcon="#{request.contextPath}/resources/images/calendar.gif"
    value="#{valueMB.dateToEvaluate}"
    datePattern="dd/MM/yyyy">
 </rich:calendar>
```

But I need **validate** that the value of that are greater than my variable `dateInitial`, if not .. then launch a message validator with the error.

Thanks for advance! and I'm sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `dayDisableFunction` attribute of rich:calendar if you want to restrict the user not to select the date earler than your initial date.

```
  <rich:calendar isDayEnabled="disableBeforeInitialDay" …>
```

and you can have javascript function like

```
function disableBeforeInitialDay(day)  {
   Date initialDay = new Date(2014,1,27); //equals to 27th Feb 2014  
   return (initialDay.getTime() - day.date.getTime() < 0);  
}
```

The above code disables all the dates earlier than your initial date.

if you want to do it server side then write your own validator class

```
 <rich:calendar .....>  
    <f:validator validatorId="myDateValidator" /> 
 </rich:calendar>  

@FacesValidator("myDateValidator")
public class MyDateValidator implements Validator {  
      @override
      public void validate(FacesContext context, UIComponent comp, Object value) throws    
       ValidatorException {

           Date date = (Date) value;
           Date refDate = new Date(2014,1,27);  
           if (date.before(refDate )) {
               String message = "Date is earlier than initial date.";
               throw new ValidatorException(new FacesMessage(message));
           }  
       }  
  }
```

If you are using richfaces 4.X the attribute should be `dayDisableFunction`
Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for your reply Srikanth, I'm making your second option but I have a problem, how I get the initial Date from my ManagedBean or other componentUI??. Because I test your example and it works fine! but I need to get date (refDate  in your example) dinamically  from MB or ComponentUI. Thanks!

Comment: you can put as a request parameter using <f:param name="initialdate" value="#{valueMB.initialDate}" and you can access it from FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap().get(initialdate); There are other ways also you can see simple examples of them here http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/4-ways-to-pass-parameter-from-jsf-page-to-backing-bean/

Comment: @Candres I feel the better approach will be to add attribute to the calendar. You can do like this <f:attribute name="initialdate" value="#{valueMB.initialDate}" /> as a child tag to the rich:calendar. You can access it in the validator as String param = (String) component.getAttributes().get("initialdate"); In this approach no need to use FacesContext.

Comment: Thank you sooo Much Srikanth! it works like a  charm!! I add the f:attribute as you indicate above and I get the parameter easily with component.getAttributes().get("initialdate") .. Thanks again man!